# Odoo Custom User Groups are only visible in developer mode

Tags: xml, odoo

In odoo 14, all custom user groups and their categories are only visible in developer mode. This visibility restriction is affecting the user profile.

Is there a way to resolve this issue and make the custom user groups and their categories visible in the user profile without requiring developer mode?

note: no need of using implies_ids